# Is there a lower bound for $\int_{B_{r}}f$ when $f$ is a positive function?

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a positive Lebesgue integrable function on a ball $B_{r}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm looking for a positive constant $c$ depending only on $f$ that satisfies
$$c\omega_nr^n\leq\int_{B_r}f$$
where $\omega_n$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

I'm also wondering if the similar result holds for a nonnegative integrable function $f$ and a nonnegative constant $c=c(f)$. Of course, $c=0$ satisfies the inequality in the this case but I need a positive constant $c$ unless $f\equiv 0$ a.e. on $B_r$.

----- Contents added -----

I have asked these questions as I thought that the existence of such a constant will help to fill out the gap of the proof of Proposition 2.27(Alexandroff's Maximum Principle of Quasilinear Equations) in "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations" by Q. Han ad F. Lin. 
In the proof it derives an inequality
$$\int_{B_M}g^n\leq\int_{\Omega}h^n<\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g^n\right)$$
where $g\in L^n_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $h\in L^n(\Omega)$ are nonnegative functions and $M$ a positive constant. (The second inequality is just an assumption of the proposition.) Then the authors conclude with no further explanation that there exists a positive constant $C$ which depends only on $g$ and $h$ such that 
$$M\leq C.$$
I think that in order to derive the second inequality from the first one we need a bound which I have suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Having $c$ depend of $f$ makes no sense, as then you can take $c = \frac{\int f}{\omega_n r^n}$ to get a tight bound.

Comment: If the constant can depend on $r$ and $f$ then it can depend on the integral, so the existence of such a constant is obvious. If it can't depend on $f$, then taking arbitrarily small constant functions shows no such bound exists.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I was looking for a constant which depends only on the function $f$ not on $r$. I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f>0$ on $B_r$, and $c \le f(x)$ for all $x\in B_r$, we know that the volume of $B_r$ is $\omega_n r^n$, so we get
$$
c\,\omega_n r^n = c\,\operatorname{Vol}(B_r) = c\int_{B_r} 1\,\mathrm dx = \int_{B_r} c\,\mathrm dx \le \int_{B_r} f(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$

Thus, $c(r,f)=\inf_{x\in B_r} f(x)$ satisfies your inequality.

However, as @martini pointed out, this infimum might be $0$.

Instead, consider the mean value of $f$ on $B_r$, i.e. $\overline f = \frac{\int_{B_r} f}{\operatorname{Vol}(B_n)}$. We easily see that
$$\int_{B_r} \overline f = \overline f\,\omega_n r^n = \int_{B_r} f.$$
Thus, $c=\overline f$ also satisfies your inequality, where $\overline f = 0$ if and only if $f\equiv 0$ almost everywhere on $B_r$, so $f>0$ is certainly sufficient for $\overline f>0$.

Of course this is an obvious bound you immediatly get from dividing the inequality by $\omega_n r^n$ in the first place.

For non-negative $f$ you will not get a bound, since $\int_{B_r} f$ might be $0$ in this case. Consider for example
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0,& \text{if $x\neq 0$,}\\
1,& \text{if $x=0$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: But we can have $c(r,f) = 0$ even if $f > 0$ ...

Comment: You are right, sorry. I edited the answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Both the essential infimum ${\rm essinf}_{B_r}(f)$ and the mean value $\frac{1}{\omega_n r^n}\int_{B_r} f$ will work, as pointed out in the answer above.

Note, also, that both of these depend on both $f$ *and* the domain (and hence on $r$), but they are sharp bounds as long as there's no further information on $f$. They may be somewhat unsatisfactory - especially the mean value which leads into a tautology. In that case, you should ask the question in a more stringent manner.

Can a bound $c$ only depending on $f$ (not on $r$) be found? Well, ${\rm essinf}_{\Omega}(f)$ is the obvious choice, with $\Omega \supset B_r$ the domain of definition of $f$. This, though, may not be positive even if ${\rm essinf}_{B_r}(f)$ is: $\Omega \supset B_r \Rightarrow {\rm essinf}_{\Omega}(f) \le {\rm essinf}_{B_r}(f)$. It would help knowing that there exists a ball $B_\rho \subset B_r$ such that ${\rm essinf}_{B_\rho}(f) > 0$, especially if your domain is *not* infinite. Do you have any such information? What is the context for this problem anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the original problem you edited in: just take $C$ to be the supremum of $M$ such that the first inequality is true. Since $\int_{B_M} g^n \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} g^n$ as $M \to \infty$ and $\int_{\Omega} h^n < \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} g^n$, we know $\int_{B_M} g^n$ must eventually stay greater than $\int_{\Omega} h^n$, and thus the supremum must be finite.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but that doesn't work because the prescribed $M$ is a fixed constant. I'm sorry for my lack of description.

Comment: @Sunghan: If $M$ is a fixed constant then of course there's a positive constant C such that $M \le C$... I don't understand your question now.

Comment: I think you need to take another close look to my question. $C$ is a constant depending only on $g$ and $h$ not on $M$, and $M$ is a given constant which has nothing to do with $g$ and $h$.

Comment: I believe my answer stands: set $C = \sup \{ r > 0 : \int_{B_r} g^n \le \int_\Omega h^n \}$.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you are saying. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Your answer does work. I think I have been thinking this problem too hard; in fact the answer was easy as you have just shown. Thanks for your help!